# How can I call the 'log()' method from the beforeSave() method in a model in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, debugging

How can I call the log() function inside the model beforeSave() function?

All three variants I used didn't work:

```
function beforeSave() {
#...
Debugger::log($y.' '.$ty);
log('test');
$this->log('testmodel');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! My model was named wrong and it never got called.
This works flawlessly:

```
$this->log($test);
```